# Whats is ->, ->> , ^ :private, s/def s/defn and : - in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Sincerelly, I read a lot of times about this commands and I don't understand what the real objectives. I'm reading pedestal documentation and I saw a lot of this command `->` and `->>` and I read in nubank's github public repository somethings as `^:private`, `s/def`, `s/defn` and `:-`

Comment: Pick **a** question. One. Not 6 questions. And make sure the one question is a) on topic here and b) not already something asked here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should go through a Clojure tutorial first to understand meaning of basic constructs and symbols. These resources can help

- https://clojure.org/guides/learn/clojure
- https://aphyr.com/tags/clojure-from-the-ground-up
- https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters

In short,

- `->` and `->>` are [*threading macros*](https://clojure.org/guides/threading_macros)
- `s/def` depends on what `s` refers to - it is commonly use as an *alias* for `clojure.spec.alpha` and `s/def` is then used to define a spec: https://clojure.org/guides/spec

  - However, there's no `clojure.spec.alpha/defn` so in that case it's probably another "schema library"; it would help if you linked the source you are talking about
- `^:private` is a [metadata](https://clojure.org/reference/metadata) key that marks a symbol as *private* within a given namespace; see also http://blogish.nomistech.com/two-ways-of-defining-private-functions/

Comment: Thank you bro! I'm learning clojure and somethings are new to me! See ya!

Comment: `s/defn` is also commonly used as an alias for Plumatic Schema:  https://github.com/plumatic/schema

Answer (score 0):

I have a template project with [a large list of documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation) at the end of the README.  The [main source file](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template/blob/master/src/clj/demo/core.clj) also shows an example of using Plumatic Schema (IMHO it is much easier to use than Spec).